# docker-machine amazon-ec2 fail during init

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I'm starting this script from my MacOS with docker 1.12.1, this script used to work ... But, now no way: I got a timeout during VM init, waiting for ssh connection?!!
Here is my code:

```
aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name ${group_name} --description "A Security Group for Docker Networking" > /dev/null 2>&1
# Permit SSH, required for Docker Machine
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol tcp --port 22    --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol tcp --port 2376  --cidr ${my_ip}/32
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol tcp --port 2377  --cidr ${my_ip}/32
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol tcp --port 5000  --cidr ${my_ip}/32
# Permit Serf ports for discovery
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol tcp --port 7946  --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol udp --port 7946  --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
# Permit VXLAN
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol tcp --port 4789  --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol udp --port 4789  --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
#Permit WEB for demo
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name ${group_name} --protocol tcp --port 80    --cidr ${my_ip}/32

docker-machine create \
   --driver amazonec2 \
   --amazonec2-region eu-central-1 \
   --amazonec2-use-private-address \
   --amazonec2-security-group ${group_name} \
leader1
```

I need to make it work to complete my project and my **docker swarm** experiment : https://github.com/itwars/docker-swarm

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Does the instance get created on AWS ?

Comment: Yes on my AWS console I got everything completed! I even can perform a direct ssh on the instance, and doing a **docker-machine ssh leader1** give me back an exit code 255 ...!